# Sklearn Pipeline with CountVectorizer and category on a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Could use some help with this one. I have a pd.DataFrame with a column of text, a category column, and a target column. I want to run a classifier model on the vectorized text, easy enough, but I want to include the category into the model.

I want to use a PipeLine so I can test different vectorizers and parameters into a GridSearchCV. I have not been able to successfully create a Pipeline with a Countvectorizer of the text and the category. I used OneHotEncoder for the category column only.

I am working on a much larger dataset but this is the premise.

Here is an example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'favorite_color':['blue green red','green green blue','red blue red',
     'green blue blue','blue red blue'],
      'Cat': ['a','b','b','c','a'],
      'target':[1,0,1,0,1]})
```

I want to vectorize "favorite color" and have "Cat" as an included feature, while "target" is the y. I am using Ridgeclassifer for a filler. I plan on running a GridSearchCV on different models.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical_preprocessing = Pipeline([('ohe', OneHotEncoder())])
text_preprocessing = Pipeline([('Vect', CountVectorizer())])

preprocess = ColumnTransformer([
                            ('categorical_preprocessing', categorical_preprocessing, ['Cat']),
                            ('text_preprocessing', text_preprocessing, ['favorite_color'])
                        ])

pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('preprocess', preprocess),
                ('rcf', RidgeClassifier())
            ])

df_features = df[['favorite_color','Cat']]
df_target = df['target']


pipeline.fit(df_features, df_target)
```

Returned Error

```
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 1, expected 5.
```

For a OneHotEncoder alone I use this:

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
X = ohe.fit_transform(df.Cat.values.reshape(-1,1))
X
```

I have been using this site for examples [Here](https://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipelines-custom-pipelines-and-pandas-integration)

Any help is always appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `favorite_color` column. To fix this you need to pass to the `text_preprocessing` the name of the column but not an array:

```
preprocess = ColumnTransformer([('categorical_preprocessing', categorical_preprocessing, ['Cat']),
                                ('text_preprocessing', text_preprocessing, 'favorite_color')])
```